# Auto-accept calls in Android

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have some code. It works, but only when the activity is open. When an application is minimized, it does not work. How do I make it work constantly?

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input keyevent " + Integer.toString(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle error here
}
```

Comment: You don't.  Not without rooting at least.  Android was built to not allow you to fake input from one app to another for security reasons.  Every time people find a way around that, Google patches the hole.  You'll never get a keypress to work when another app has the foreground, unless the phone is rooted.

Comment: But there are in fact working answering machines

Comment: Then they don't do it via keypress faking.

Comment: the question is, just how to do it differently